# changing the color of button after some time tcl tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to change the color of the radio button after some time.
Here is the code i tried,

```
set field1 [radiobutton .field1 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled" ]
set field2 [radiobutton .field2 -disabledforeground red -state "disabled"]
set field3 [radiobutton .field3 -disabledforeground green -state "disabled"]

grid $field1 -row 0 -column 0
grid $field2 -row 0 -column 1
grid $field3 -row 0 -column 2

after 2000
$field1 configure -disabledforeground red
grid $field1 -row 0 -column 0
```

Window opens only after the changing the color.

How to see the change of color dynamically in run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do the trick. I'm not sure if it's the best way, though.

```
set field1 [radiobutton .field1 -disabledforeground green -state disabled]
set field2 [radiobutton .field2 -disabledforeground red -state disabled]
set field3 [radiobutton .field3 -disabledforeground green -state disabled]

grid $field1 $field2 $field3

bind .field1 <Map> [list after 2000 {changeDisabledColor %W red}]

proc changeDisabledColor {w color} {
    $w configure -disabledforeground $color
}
```

A few thoughts about this:

1. `after 2000` means that the command sleeps for two seconds before returning, and during that time, the gui is unresponsive. `after 2000` *script* means that the command returns immediately after scheduling an event to happen in two seconds.
2. The `Map` event is triggered for a window when that window is added to the set of windows to display, but before it it's size and position are calculated. AFAICT it's a good event to latch onto if one wants to time some configuration to the appearance of the window.
3. The handler for `.field1 <Map>` doesn't have to be a call to a command procedure: `bind .field1 <Map> [list after 2000 {%W configure -disabledforeground red}]` should work too. It's often a good idea to use a call like in my example, because that is usually more convenient to build on later.

Documentation: [after](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/after.htm), [bind](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm), [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [radiobutton](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/radiobutton.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)